# Help understanding the Min song 追追追

Tags: translation, topolect, hokkien, songs

#### Cross-post notice

I already posted the question [here](https://www.quora.com/Could-you-help-me-finish-deciphering-the-Min-Nan-Hokkien-song-%E8%BF%BD%E8%BF%BD%E8%BF%BD-starting-from-the-video-text-Tai-lo-and-translation-attempt-in-the-comment-to-the-question), but have since received only one helpful answer, which promised "more later" but never came back with "more". Since it's been a week, I thought it would be OK to cross-post.

#### Video and lyrics (captions with fixes)

The song in question is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-43hn-SO6U). The lyrics below are from the captions, with the bracketed additions being spelling fixes aiming for MoE-endorsed spelling:

千江水千江月
千里帆千重山
千里江山我尚【上】水【媠】
万里月万里城
万里愁万里烟
万里风霜我尚【上】妖娇
什么【啥物】款的杀气
什么【啥物】款的角色
什么【啥物】款的枭雄
迫阮策马坠风尘
什么【啥物】款的爱情
什么【啥物】款的坠落
什么【啥物】款的温柔
后【予】阮日夜拢想你
真久以前狼主的传说
如今狼烟再起
真久以前狼主的传说
如今狼烟再起

啊追追追
追着你的心
追着你的人
追着你的情
追着你的无讲理
啊烦烦烦
烦过这世人
心肝如倉倉【挐氅氅】
找【揣】无酒来浇【沃】
咽起啦
砉【莫】搁【阁】稀你【遐尔】大声
对我说【讲】话
啊乱乱乱
女人的心
豆腐做的
为你破碎
任由针底【咧】划【揻】

#### Rough phonetic transcription (approximate Tai-lo)

What follows is my rough transcription of the sounds:

Tshian kang tsui tshian kang gueh
Tshian li phan tshian tiong san
Tshian li kang-san gua siong sui
Ban li gueh ban li sia
Ban li siu ban li ian
Ban li hong-song gua siong iau-kiau
Siam-meh khuan--e sat-khi
Siam-meh khuan--e kak-sik
Siam-meh khuan--e hiau-hiong
Pik gun tshik-ma tui hong-tin
Siam-meh khuan--e ai-tsing
Siam-meh khuan--e tui-loh
Siam-meh khuan--e un-liu
Hoo gun lit-ia long siunn li
Tsin ku i-tsing long-tsu--e thuan-suat
Lu-kim long-ian tsai khi
Tsin ku i-tsing long-tsu--e thuan-suat
Lu-kim long-ian tsai khi

Ah tui tui tui
Tui-tioh li-e sim
Tui-tioh li--e lang
Tui-tioh li--e tsing
Tui-tioh li--e bo-kong-li
Ah huan huan huan
Huan-kue tsit-si-lang
Sim-kuann lu-tshang-tshang
Tshue bo tsiu lai ak
En khi--lah
Mai koh hia-ni tua-siann
Tui gua kong-ue
Ah luan luan luan
Lu-lim--e sim
Tau-hu tsue--e
Ui li pho-tshui
Lim-iu tsiam teh ui

#### Translation attempt

The following is my translation attempt:

1000 rivers of water, 1000 rivers of moon (moonlit rivers?),
1000 miles of sails, 1000 overlapping mountains,
1000 rivers and mountains, I’m the most beautiful
A myriad miles of moon, a myriad miles of castles,
A myriad miles of anxiety, a myriad miles of smoke (?),
A myriad miles of winds and frost, I’m the most seductive.
What kind of murderous aura,
What kind of character,
What kind of formidable person
Will force me to urge my horse to fall to travel fatigue?
What kind of love,
What kind of crash-fall,
What kind of tenderness
Will make me think of you day and night?
The legend of the very long-ago wolf-master / foreign leader
Now the wolf-smoke (??) rises again.
The legend of the very long-ago wolf-master / foreign leader
Now the wolf-smoke (??) rises again.

Ah chasing chasing chasing
Chasing your heart (Or heart chasing you)
Chasing your person (Or person/people chasing you)
Chasing your love (Or the love of chasing you)
Chasing your unreasonableness (Or the unreasonableness of chasing you)
Ah vexed vexed vexed
I’m vexed in this life
My heart is crazy confused
It can’t find alcohol to drench itself in
Drink up!
With such a loud voice don’t again
Speak to me
Ah chaotic chaotic chaotic
Heart of a woman
Made of tofu
Broken for you
Even though it’s being stabbed by needles (?) (Or “Needles are freely stabbing it”?)

#### Questions

A few specific questions:

1. Moonlit rivers or rivers of moon? What would the latter mean?
2. What is this "legend of the wolf-master / foreign leader"? And which translation is correct?
3. What's with all the references to smoke? And what is the "wolf-smoke"?
4. Which of the translations of the lines with bracketed alternate translations are correct?

### UPDATE

#### Translation update

With some info from here and some from there, I now update my translation attempt as per [my Quora self-answer](https://www.quora.com/Could-you-help-me-finish-deciphering-the-Min-Nan-Hokkien-song-%E8%BF%BD%E8%BF%BD%E8%BF%BD-starting-from-the-video-text-Tai-lo-and-translation-attempt-in-the-comment-to-the-question/answer/Michele-Gorro-Gorini).

1000 rivers with water, 1000 rivers with moon[light],
1000 miles of sails, 1000 overlapping mountains, [perhaps “heavy (tiōng) mountains (san)”?]
1000 miles of rivers and mountains [aka of landscape/scenery], I’m the most beautiful.
A myriad miles of moon, a myriad miles of castles/cities,
A myriad miles of grief, a myriad miles of smoke [signals],
A myriad miles of wind and frost, I’m the most seductive.
What kind of murderous aura,
What kind of character/role,
What kind of hero
Will force me to urge my horse till it falls to the ground [lit. windblown dust]?
What kind of love,
What kind of downfall,
What kind of tenderness
Will make me think of you day and night?
The legend of the very long-ago Wolf King [Gengis Khan apparently].
Now the smoke signals rise again.
The legend of the very long-ago Wolf King [Gengis Khan apparently].
Now the smoke signals rise again.

Ah chasing chasing chasing,
Chasing your heart,
Chasing your body,
Chasing your love,
Chasing your nonsense!
Ah vexed vexed vexed,
I’m vexed in this life,
My heart is a hot mess,
It can’t find alcohol to drench itself in.
I’ve had enough!
With such a loud voice don’t again
Speak to me!
Ah chaotic chaotic chaotic
Heart of a woman,
Made of tofu,
Broken for you,
Let it be stabbed by needles!

#### Updated text and romanization

Here is the final text with Tai-lo:

千江水，千江月， | Tshian kang tsuí, tshian kang gue̍h,
千里帆，千重山， | Tshian lí phâng, tshian tiông san,
千里江山……我上媠； | Tshian lí kang-san… guá siōng suí;
万里月，万里城， | Bān lí gue̍h, bān lí siânn,
万里愁，万里煙， | Bān lí tshiû, bān lí ian,
万里风霜……我上妖嬌。 | Bān lí hong-song… guá siōng iau-kiau.
啥物款的杀气， | Siám-mi̍h khuán—ê sat-khì,
啥物款的角色， | Siám-mi̍h khuán—ê kak-sik,
啥物款的枭雄 | Siám-mi̍h khuán—-ê hiau-hiông
迫阮策马坠风尘？ | Pik gún tshik má tuī hong-tîn?
啥物款的爱情， | Siám-mi̍h khuán—ê ài-tsîng,
啥物款的坠落， | Siám-mi̍h khuán—ê tuī-lo̍h,
啥物款的温柔 | Siám-mi̍h khuán—ê un-liû
予阮日夜拢想你？ | Hōo gún li̍t-iā lóng siūnn lí?
真久以前，狼主的传说， | Tsin kú í-tsîng, long tsú—ê tuân-suat,
如今狼烟再起！ | Lû-kim long ian tsài khí!
真久以前，狼主的传说， | Tsin kú í-tsîng, long tsú—ê tuân-suat,
如今狼烟再起！ | Lû-kim long ian tsài khí!

啊～追，追，追， | Ah tui, tui, tui,
追着你的心， | Tui-tio̍h lí—ê sim,
追着你的人， | Tui-tio̍h lí—ê lâng,
追着你的情， | Tui-tio̍h lí—ê tsîng,
追着你的无讲理！ | Tui-tio̍h lí—ê bô-kóng-lí!
啊～烦，烦，烦， | Ah huân, huân, huân,
烦过这世人， | Huân-kuè tsit-sì-lâng,
心肝挐氅氅， | Sim-kuann lû-tsháng-tsháng,
揣无酒来沃。 | Tshuē bô tsiú lâi ak.
厌气啦！ | Iàn-khì—lah!
莫阁遐尔大声对我讲话！ | Mài koh hiah-nī tuā-siann tuì guá kóng-uē!
啊～乱，乱，乱， | Ah luān, luān, luān,
女人的心， | Lú-lîn ê sim,
豆腐做的， | Tāu-hū tsuè--ê,
为你破碎， | Uī lí phò-tshuì,
任由针咧揻！ | Līm iû tsiam teh ui!

#### New question list

The questions are now:

1. There is [another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNo3LuZXA1w) which, in its English captions, renders 任由针咧揻 as «like going under a needle», how does 任由 become "like"?
2. "Overlapping mountains" or "heavy mountains"? What does 重山 mean, and if the former, in what sense "overlapping"?
3. Siânn: castles or cities?
4. What smoke is being referred to in the first part?
5. Why is that legend of the Wolf-King mentioned here? What smoke signals are rising again? What does that passage mean, besides the literal translation?
6. Any other comments on the translation :)?

Answer (score 1):

尚水 - prefer water

尚妖娇 - prefer charming ladies

[狼烟](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%8B%BC%E7%83%9F/14364) - smoke signal for war

狼主 lord of wolves (Genghis Khan's legend referring the tale of a gray wolf and a white deer. 狼主 here might just a generic term for great warlord)

The subtitles are all correct

Comment: If 水 were actually water, I'd expect it to be pronounced tsuí, not suí as in the video. In fact, 千江水 has tsuí in it. Is there any reason 尚水 would use the 文读 instead of the 白读 I'm expecting?

Also, that last statement is definitely too general-sounding. There's no way you're claiming 稀你 isn't a lousy phonetic rendition of hiah-ni = 那么, right?

Comment: As you will see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNo3LuZXA1w), the captions of the video I first gave were NOT all correct, and my reading of the first two things you refer to was actually correct. In fact, all my fixes were correct, and I was missing only one fix before getting MoE spelling.

Answer (score 1):

你這首歌是台語歌(福建話)。

**OP's questions:**

1.Moonlit rivers or rivers of moon? What would the latter mean?

**The original phrase of "千江水千江月" is "千江有水千江月". Which means thousands(not just 1000) of moonlight river, and each moonlight river has it's own view**

2.What is this "legend of the wolf-master / foreign leader"? And which translation is correct?

**legend of the wolf-master => 狼主的傳說.**

3.What's with all the references to smoke? And what is the "wolf-smoke"?

**wolf-smoke，a smoke signal of emergency(usually means war,intruders...). Google keyword "烽火台" for more informantion.**

4.Which of the translations of the lines with bracketed alternate translations are correct?

**YES, Correct.**

**我尚水(台語、福建話) means "I’m the most beautiful". OP's translation is correct.**

Comment: In the lines «Chasing your heart (Or heart chasing you)», «Chasing your person (Or person/people chasing you)», «Chasing your love (Or the love of chasing you)», «Chasing your unreasonableness (Or the unreasonableness of chasing you)», and «Even though it’s being stabbed by needles (?) (Or “Needles are freely stabbing it”?)», I gave two translation options, which is the correct one?

What is this 狼主的传说? I suspect there is a metaphor in this reference, and in the smoke signal right after it…